# Which algorithm do I need to use to calculate the error?

Tags: neural-networks, ai-design

I am building a neural network for a AI whose goal is to learn to implement the XOR logical function.I have this code so far:

```
class Node:
  prevNodes = []
  b = 0.5; 

def __init__(self,value,nextNode):
    self.value = value
    self.nextNode = nextNode
    self.nextNode.value += self.value * b
    self.nextNode.prevNodes.append(self)

def changeB(error):
    b +=error;

def printVal(self):
    print(self.value+"\n")


class Network:

def __init__(self,nodes):
    self.nodes = nodes

def calcOutput(self):
    finalNode = self.nodes
    while self.nodes.nextNode is not None:
        finalNode = self.nodes.nextNode
    return 1-pow(e,-(finalNode.value))

def digitize(val):
    if val<0.5:
        val = 0
    else:
        val = 1

def correctBiases():


def checkAnswer():

    if input("is this answer correct?") is not digitize(calcOutput()):

        correctBiases()
```

Now I am writing the `correctBiases()` function. Which algorithm do I need to use to calculate the `error`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a summarized version of the explanation in [Haykin 1994](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/knowledge-engineering-review/article/abs/neural-networks-a-comprehensive-foundation-by-simon-haykin-macmillan-1994-isbn-0023527817/EB35EC581662FFC75E3FCAD4DDB9FDD1), section 4.3.  ([Rumelhart et al 1986](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Learning-representations-by-back-propagating-errors-Rumelhart-Hinton/052b1d8ce63b07fec3de9dbb583772d860b7c769) being the original reference, but Haykin breaks it down nicely for beginners.)

$\underbrace{\Delta w_{ji}(n)}_\textrm{weight correction} = \underbrace{\eta}_\textrm{learning rate }\cdot \underbrace{\delta_i(n)}_\textrm{ local gradient }\cdot \underbrace{y_i(n)}_\textrm{ input signal of neuron j }$

$\delta_j(n) = \psi^{'}_j\left(v_j\left(n\right)\right)\, e_j(n)$

$e_j(n) = d_j(n) - y_j(n)$ is the error for output neuron $j$

$e_j(n) = \sum\limits_k \delta_k(n)\, w_{kj}(n)$ is the error for hidden neuron $j$.

$\psi$ is the activation function. $d$ is the correct value. $y$ is the predicted value. $w$ is the weight matrix.

Note that what you're calling the error in the question is more commonly the "weight correction". The error is just one part of that.

Comment: I havent taken a  Deep learning class at my university yet so my terms are layman terms.Thanks a lot btw!

Comment: Not a problem. I just wanted to avoid confusion since I've got an "error" term here that isn't what you meant by error.